# quickblox OnMessageListener is not receiveing qbprivate message with attachment

Tags: android, quickblox

i have implemented quickblox successfully earlier for my android chat apps for only text chat. this time i want to send message with image as attachment. File is sending successfully ( i have checked it in quickblox admin Content panel). But in the receiver part it is not displaying image or text. I am getting nor any Exception/ error or text in logcat. So it's very difficult to trace out the wrong code, i m doing. plz help.
MyChatControlle
------------------------`private QBPrivateChatManagerListener chatManagerListener=new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(QBPrivateChat qbPrivateChat, boolean b) {
            if(!b) {
                qbPrivateChat.addMessageListener(myListener);
            }
        }

### };`

```
private QBMessageListener myListener=new QBMessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(QBChat qbChat, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage) {
        int frm=qbChatMessage.getSenderId();
        int tos=qbChatMessage.getRecipientId();
        System.out.println(String.format(">>> Message received (from=%s, to=%s): %s", frm, tos, qbChatMessage.getBody()));
        if (onMessageReceivedListener != null) {
            onMessageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(qbChatMessage);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void processError(QBChat qbChat, QBChatException e, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage) { }
```

### };

### ChatActivity

```
 MyChatController.OnMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener = new MyChatController.OnMessageReceivedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final QBChatMessage msg) {
        try {
            final String mmsg = msg.getBody();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receiving..."+mmsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"#A#B#"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest version of QuickBlox Android SDK without chat managers. In newest versions you can use QBChatDialog model to perform all chat functions. Additionally check all parameters of your attachment, they mast be not null and not empty. Can you provide message, which didn't catch by listener (.xml from logcat)?

Comment: I have already done Login Activity and UserList Activity so, if i change the sdk, then i have to start from first. Both Activity is doing well without any exception. btw i am not getting any exception in logcat

Comment: Ok. Can you enable chat's logs QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true); before login to chant and provide message with attachment, which didn't catch by listener. In logs it looks like

Comment: D/SMACK: RECV (0): <message from="303796-3@chat.quickblox.com/android_00000000-xxxx" to="305264-3@chat.quickblox.com" type="chat" id="xxxxx" xmlns="jabber:client"><body>Attachment</body><markable xmlns="urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0"/><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><attachment url="xxxx" type="photo" id="294847"/><dialog_id>xxxxxxxxx</dialog_id><date_sent>1493797100</date_sent><save_to_history>1</save_to_history><message_id>xxxxxx</message_id></extraParams></message>